# SQLite: database cannot be closed while a transaction is in progress

Tags: sqlite, react-native

Using `react-native-sqlite-storage`, I am trying to invoke `SQLite.deleteDatabase({ name }, resolve, reject);` and I am getting the error `database cannot be closed while a transaction is in progress`. I haven't been able to figure out how to handle this.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: @Mauricio i do not remember if a solution was found for this issue. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I am using react-native-sqlite-storage with typeorm and I started running into this issue when I was iterating on my DB design locally. Turns out when I added a constructor to my entity class for which tables are created from it was throwing an error in there which causes the initial table creation to fail silently. So during the table creations it was running it in a transaction and since it failed somehow the connection never got closed. I fixed the constructor issue and it stopped giving me the error.

In summary, the issue is something is failing that the library is trying to handle for you and you are not handling it properly. Place debugger points and find the point of failure and that should get rid of this issue.